# XBMC Black Screen HDMI Output on Media Autoplay

Tags: raspbmc, hdmi, video, display

I have a Raspberry Pi (Model B - 512MB) that I have XBMC running on. I use it for a media player and when it works I'm really happy with it. But there is this annoying bug that I'm running into where about 50% of the time if auto-play starts a video file, the audio works for it, but the screen goes black. I don't even need to restart the Pi to get the video back working, just stopping the video and restarting it again from the menu fixes whatever is wrong.

Any ideas on the bug? Any ideas on debugging?

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. Most likely decoder spits out unexpected data that crashes the frame buffer. So you need to stop and start. You should report that to XBMC instead.

Answer (score 4):

Also got this problem. Screen goes blank when autoplay starts a new video in a lower resolution than the one the TV/Display is running with.

I can get the video working again by going to
System→Settings→System→Video Output→Video Calibration
Don't need to change anything, Will just work again after quiting the menu. Although this solution is not feasible (cause you always need to got to the menu every so often), but it may serve to find the error hopefully